# Create an array of specific elements from another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that can't be changed in terms of the element positions:

```
var array = ['item1', 'section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4', 'section5', 'prod1', 'prod2']
```

I want to make a new array from 'array' that takes the elements from position 1 - 5 (so all the section elements). It needs to be by position as the section elements make change by name.

Comment: `var newArray = array.slice(1,6)` the end index will be exclusive, start index will be inclusive

Comment: `console.log(array.slice(1,6))`

Comment: it needs to be by position as the section elements make change by name ???

Comment: Do you mean the number on the section element might change: like `section1` might change to `section12`, or `section1` might change to something completely different like `tree1`?

Comment: @Andy yes the element might change from `section1` to `area5` etc so I needed the index position rather than the element name.

Comment: @foreverlearning, would they all change, or might only one of them change?

Comment: @Andy they might all change in terms of their name, but their index position will remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var array2=array.slice(1,6)
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for more information.

Comment: Try to give a link which points to developer.mozilla.com and free my downvote from your post.  :|

Comment: I changed it. The website is actually developer.mozilla.org.

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have an array like this

```
 const FILES_WITH_10_ASSETS = [
  '../assets/uploads/Desktop-300x600.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Desktop-728x90.png',
  '../assets/uploads/Mobile-160x600.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Mobile-300X50.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Mobile-320x50.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Mobile-320x480.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Mobile-1024x768.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Tablet-300x250.jpeg',
  '../assets/uploads/Tablet-Interstitial-320x480.gif',
  '../assets/uploads/Tablet-Interstitial-320x480.jpeg'
];
```

now we want some specific items from an array, we will create a function for this, here I have stored the function in an constant for further use

```
const SELECT_ASSETS = function(assetName: string) {
  let filtered_assets: string[] = [];
  for (let i in FILES_WITH_10_ASSETS) {
    if (FILES_WITH_10_ASSETS[i].includes(assetName) === true) {
      filtered_assets.push(FILES_WITH_10_ASSETS[i]);
    }
  }
  return filtered_assets;
};
```

and we call the method like this in our file

```
const ASSETS_NAME = SELECT_ASSETS(ASSET_NAME);
```

now we can pass the assets name to any function or method, if we pass the ASSET_NAME as Tablet we will get all three tablet paths, or if we change it to Mobile, we will get all five Mobile paths